# Woocommerce and different checkout field for different countries

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-wpml

I am considering to migrate from Magento to Woocommerce. My main site is for Japan, and the other is in English.

I read you can go for either WPML or multisite.

I understood WPML can handle multi language and multi currency. But how about different checkout form for different countries?
I have now Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro installed.

The address field order for Japan is basically opposite to the western way. Meaning,

> Postcode, Region,  City,  Street

instead

> Street, City, Postcode, Region, Country

Is it possible to have different checkout field order for different countries without making multisite?
Or do I need to make multisite to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter allows you to alter the order of fields displayed in the checkout page, you can add a condition in the callback to check for the country or language.

Comment: Can you give me more detailed explanation how I can achieve this?

Comment: The filter gives access to the fields array and you can change the order of array or unset or add new fields  refer [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2)

Comment: can you tell me how to add a condition in the callback to check if it is Japan? Then the fields should be reordered?

Comment: Depends on how you are managing the Japan and English site, if you are using any plugin to choose a country and you must use the plugin-specific condition. If you are using multisite then check for the blog id of the site.